# Celery Cannot find a module in my Django project

Tags: django, celery

I have a Django 2.0 project using celery 4.2.1 and redis 2.10.6. The django project has two apps, memorabilia and face_recognition. I have it all successfully running tasks with django running on my development machine. I uploaded everything to my git server, then installed the apps on my laptop from git, updated all requirements, etc. Both are Ubuntu machines. I am not using django-celery.

When I try to run `celery -A MemorabiliaJSON worker -l debug`,

I get an exception saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition.tasks'`

I am not sure how to fix this, as the same code base is running on my development machine.

My file structure is:

```
├── celery.sh
├── face_recognition
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── memorabilia
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── fields.py
│   ├── fixtures
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── logs
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── storage.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── validators.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── widgets.py
├── MemorabiliaJSON
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── default_images
│   ├── documents
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings
│   ├── static
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── celery.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
├── requirements.txt
└── tests
```

MemorabiliaJSON/celery.py

```
# http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.apps import apps
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MemorabiliaJSON.settings.tsunami')

app = Celery('MemorabiliaJSON')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
#app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()])
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
    (memorabilia-JSON) mark@octopus:~/python-projects/memorabilia-JSON
```

`face_recognition/__init__.py`

```
default_app_config = 'face_recognition.apps.FaceRecognitionConfig'
```

`memorabilia/__init__.py`

```
default_app_config = 'memorabilia.apps.MemorabiliaConfig'
```

INSTALLED_APPS has these two apps

```
'memorabilia.apps.MemorabiliaConfig',
'face_recognition.apps.FaceRecognitionConfig',
```